# Tooltip is hiding behind the heading of table

Tags: html, css, handsontable

I am having a question regarding the tooltip, the tooltip is hiding behind the table heading or it is displaying in one box it is not showing out.

Please, refer to the image  where the tip is hiding behind the another div
(marketing shown in image is in the tip):

[image]

```css
.tooltipCustom {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltipCustom .tooltipCustomtext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #efeee6;
  color: #868474;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltipCustom:hover .tooltipCustomtext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='tooltipCustom'>

  <sup style="vertical-align: top">
    Something
   </sup>

  <span class='tooltipCustomtext'> 
    Underlying price: List price <br/>
    Applied Discounts: Marketing
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: what is fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fix it

```
/* Position the tooltip */
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px;
```

For example

```
/* Position the tooltip */
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the div above has a z-index defined, you need to put a higher z-index value on your tooltip to be on the front of previous div:

```
.mypreviousDiv {
  z-index: 100;
}

.tooltipCustom .tooltipCustomtext {
   z-index: 101; // ou higher, for tooltips we can put 9999
}
```